# return null value in the JSON_EXTRACT

Tags: mysql, json, function, error-handling, extract

**MyJsonArray**

```
[{"ID":"D29","PersonID":"23616639"},{"ID":"D30","PersonID":"22629626"}]
```

and I want from sql Function set this array in to my Table but return null value in the variable and not set record in My database
my function:

```
    DELIMITER $$
CREATE DEFINER=`toshiari`@`localhost` FUNCTION `setTitleRecords`(`Title` VARCHAR(166) CHARACTER SET utf8mb4 COLLATE utf8mb4_unicode_ci, `List` JSON) RETURNS int(4)
BEGIN
    DECLARE Item                INT;
    DECLARE HolderLENGTH        INT;
    DECLARE ValidJson           INT;
    DECLARE ID                  VARCHAR(166);
    DECLARE PersonID            VARCHAR(166);
    DECLARE S1                  VARCHAR(166);
    DECLARE S2                  VARCHAR(166);
    SET ValidJson = (SELECT JSON_VALID(List));
    IF ValidJson = 1 THEN 
        SET HolderLENGTH = (SELECT JSON_LENGTH(List));
        SET Item = 0;
        WHILE Item < HolderLENGTH DO
            SET S1 = CONCAT("'$[",Item, "].ID'");
            SET S2 = CONCAT("'$[",Item, "].PersonID'");
            SET ID       = (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(List,S1));
            SET PersonID = (SELECT JSON_EXTRACT(List,S2));
            INSERT INTO `Titles`(`ID`,`PersonID`,`Title`) VALUES (ID, PersonID, Title);
            SET Item = Item + 1;
        END WHILE;
        RETURN 3;       
    ELSE
        RETURN 2;       
    END IF;
END$$
DELIMITER ;
```

when I use this command in the Sql commands no problem and return true value

```
SELECT JSON_EXTRACT('[{"ID":"D29","PersonID":"23616639"},{"ID":"D30","PersonID":"22629626"}]','$[0].ID')  return "D29"
```

return 
 "D29" 
but in when run function from this code 
return error and said:

```
SET @p0='DR'; SET @p1='[{\"ID\":\"D29\",\"PersonID\":\"23616639\"},{\"ID\":\"D30\",\"PersonID\":\"22629626\"}]'; SELECT `setTitleRecords`(@p0, @p1) AS `setTitleRecords`;


#4042 - Syntax error in JSON path in argument 2 to function 'json_extract' at position 1
```

Comment: You are missing two variable declarations: `DECLARE ID                  VARCHAR(100);  DECLARE PersonID VARCHAR(100);`

Comment: excuse me and thank you, sorry I forget those line in my code, But there is still a problem

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I created a little test, in order to reproduce your issues. Basically you just need to redeclare S1 and S2, in the following way:

```
SET S1 = CONCAT('$[',Item,'].ID');
SET S2 = CONCAT('$[',Item,'].PersonID');
```

> And that's it. You can check the test in the following url: https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/2TPgF868snjwcHN3uwoSEA/0

Comment: thank you very much master !!! Can I ask you about your opinion logic code!?  I mean in the for  "'while loop'" and... or there is better way for my purpose !?

Comment: Your solution is correct; IMHO the ideal should be storing it in a table, but, one object per row, instead of a jsonarray, but is just my opinion.